# How to add hotspot sphere in Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to add hotspot sphere to a 3D .nwd model which has to be viewed in Autodesk Forge Viewer. Please suggest how hotspot can be added to .nwd naviseworks file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to add hotspots to a model in Forge Viewer:

- by adding custom "point clouds" into the scene: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card
- by adding custom 3D geometry: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/
- by overlaying the 3D viewport with HTML elements; the [Forge Digital Twin](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-digital-twin) sample code shows how you can compute 2D positions from Forge model coordinates, specifically in the [IssueExtension](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-digital-twin/blob/master/public/scripts/extensions/issues.js)

Comment: Thank you very  much. Its helpful . I will explore those options. Just wanted to know can we create hotspot to a .NWD file by any of Autodesk product and bring the model into Forge viewer with hotspot.

Comment: Just wanted to know can we create hotspot to a .NWD file by any of Autodesk product and bring the model into Forge viewer with hotspot.